# Conflict in c++ between the address of the pointer and the address stored in the pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

Consider this C++ program:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int x = 7;
    int *ip = &x;
    cout << "the value of x is " << x <<endl;
    cout << "the address of x is " << &x <<endl;
    cout << "the address stored at ip is "<< ip <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here's what I get as output:

```
the value of x is 7
the address of x is 0x28ff08
the address stored at the pointer is 0x28ff08
```

This makes sense to me. However, if I change the code to the following, I get a different set of outputs:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int x = 7;
    int *ip = &x;
    cout << "the value of x is " << x <<endl;
    cout << "the address of x is " << &x <<endl;
    cout << "the address of the ip itself is "<< &ip <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Now, I'm getting this output:

```
the value of x is 7
the address of x is 0x28ff0c
the address of the ip itself is 0x28ff08
```

In the first code, the address of the variable `x` and the address stored at the pointer `ip` are the same, which makes sense to me. But in the second program, the address of `ip` itself remains the same, but the address of `x` seems to be changing, which I find confusing. I'd expected the address of the variable `x` remains the same as in the first program and for the address of the pointer to change.

Can someone explain what's going on here?

Comment: a) Why would you expect that and b) why do you care to begin with?

Comment: I dont really get what the question is about. Can you include the output in the question instead of just screenshots and maybe highlight the addresses that you expect to be same/differrent?

Comment: do you expect the address of `x` in the second snippet to be the same as the address of `x` in the first snippet? If yes, why? You cant even count on `x` being stored in the same memory when you run the same code twice

Comment: There is no conflict, only wrong expectation.

Comment: for the first block of code this is the result (the value of x is 7,
the address of x is 0x28ff08,
the address stored at the pointer is 0x28ff08)

Comment: the result for the second block of code is (the value of x is 7,
the address of x is 0x28ff0c,
the address stored at the pointer is 0x28ff08)

Comment: @Slava why is it a wrong expectation?

Comment: @MohammedAmer because there is nothing that would provide such guarantee, you just expect it based on your idea, which is wrong.

Comment: please add it to the question, and I am still not sure what addresses you expect to be same...

Comment: In the first case no one cares about where `ip` is, so the compiler has tonnes of leeway. `ip` might not have an address at all; it could just be sitting in a register. In the second, `ip` must have an address, because the program prints it, and this moves stuff around on you.

Answer (score 1):

The values in first code is same because the value of ip is address of x (same thing, ip keeping address of x). But in second code results are different because address of x is not address of ip (ip is different variable - pointer capable to hold addresses of other variables). Where computer will decide to create them - who knows. I think that was just coincidence where one variable is created on same address and second on different.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be getting confused between the value of the pointee, the address of the pointee, the value of the pointer, and the address of the pointer. I think this is probably best explained through a picture. If you write

```
int  x  = 7;
int* ip = &x;
```

then, in memory, things look something like this:

```
  +-----------+                 +-----------+
  |     7     |  <------------  | Address A |
  +-----------+                 +-----------+
      int x                        int* ip
    Address A                     Address B
```

Here, the variable `x` is stored at some location (call it `A`) and it holds the value `7`. The variable `ip` is stored at some location (call it `B`) and it holds as its value the address `A`. Note that `A` and `B` have to be different from one another, because `x` and `ip` occupy separate memory locations.

Now, think about what happens when you write

```
cout << x << endl;
```

This prints out the value stored in `x`, which is `7`. (I assume that's not very surprising.)

If you write

```
cout << &x << endl;
```

you are printing out the address that `x` sits at. That will be whatever the value of `A` happens to be, and it'll vary from program run to program run.

If you write

```
cout << ip << endl;
```

you are printing out the value stored in `ip`. Since `ip` points to `x`, the value stored in `ip` is the address of `x`, which is whatever `A` happens to be.

However, if you write

```
cout << &ip << endl;
```

you are printing out the address of the `ip` variable. That address is denoted above by `B` and it depends on the particular run of the program. Note that `A` and `B` are *not* the same thing, so you should expect to see different values here.

To recap:

```
  +-----------+                 +-----------+
  |     7     |  <------------  | Address A |
  +-----------+                 +-----------+
      int x                        int* ip
    Address A                     Address B

       cout <<   x << endl; // Prints 7, the contents of x.
       cout <<  &x << endl; // Prints A, the address of x.
       cout <<  ip << endl; // Prints A, the contents of ip.
       cout << &ip << endl; // Prints B, the address of ip.
```

In your case, it seems like `A`, the address of `x`, was `0x28ff0c` and the address of `ip` (`B`) was `0x28ff08`. This doesn't mean that the address of `x` changed, but rather indicates that `ip` and `x` occupy different memory addresses.